# How to open a link using a CardView

Tags: android-studio, hyperlink, android-cardview

What I want to do is to click on a CardView send me directly to the browser with a link already inserted as I can achieve that would greatly appreciate your help  :).

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code. Replace it with the id of your cardview in place of your_cardview_id

```
    CardView cardView;
    cardView = findViewById(R.id.your_cardview_id);

    cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
            startActivity(browserIntent);
        }
    });
```